# Configure fontconfig to ignore bitmaps in scalable fonts

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I have the Microsoft C-Fonts installed, and they're wonderful.  However, Calibri appears as a bitmap font in a lot of the sizes that it appears. How do I tell fontconfig to forbid Calibri (and Cambria,etc.) from being rendered from the embedded bitmaps? I already have `70-no-bitmaps.conf` in my `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` directory.

The fonts in question can be [extracted from the PowerPoint Viewer](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/01/calibri-linux-vista-fonts-download.html).

Comment: AFAIK those fonts aren't freely distributable?  (So I can't test them.)  But are you sure they use bitmaps, and don't just disable antialiassing?

Comment: @JanC The fonts do indeed use prerendered bitmaps.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf` only rejects bitmap fonts, they don't disable embedded bitmaps, which is the case here. I don't know why they didn't put the setting to disable embedded bitmaps in the same conf file. Anyways, put the following in your `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf` (or, for older versions of Ubuntu, in `~/.fonts.conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
      <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

This will disable embedded bitmap for all fonts. If you want to disable only for select fonts, add `<test>` element:

```
<test name="family" compare="contains">
  <string>Calibri</string>
  <string>Cambria</string>
</test>
```

before `<edit ...`.

Comment: Should this be put in /etc/fonts/conf.d, or better in /etc/fonts/conf.avail and symlinked to conf.d, like all the other config files? Is this reserved for the config files provided by the ubuntu distribution? Does it matter?

Comment: @knb by default ubuntu/debian settings, fontconfig will load anything in `~/.fonts.conf.d/` as well. So I suggest you put it there to avoid mucking with system configs. Unless you want to make it available to all users, then you can put it in `/etc/fonts/conf.d`, or put it in `avail` and symlink it to `conf.d` to use it when you need it (you can delete the symlink when you feel like turning it on, vice versa)

Comment: With current versions of fontconfig, the file name must be `~/.fonts.conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf` it won't be loaded if it isn't prefixed with a number. Run for example `FC_DEBUG=1024 gedit` to see if your configuration is loaded at all if it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @pascal +1 for FC_DEBUG. And no, number before name was not necessary on 10.04 LTS, just having it named `.fonts.config` was enough. What version of fontconfig you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give you have the "<string>" attribute mentioned twice in the "<test>" stanza. This causes a warning on Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04. To eliminate the warning the stanza in the file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <test name="family" compare="contains">
       <string>Calibri</string>
       <string>Cambria</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
      <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```